# Можно ли задать и код завершения, и текст вывода в stderr в исключении python?

Tags: python, исключения, argparse

Исключение `SystemExit` позволяет задавать код завершения. Также оно позволяет задавать текст вывода в stderr (который как и ожидается будет напечатан только если исключение не отловлено). Но при этом, код завершения может быть равен только 1. Т.е. указать и то и другое нельзя, что как по мне не удобно, может потребоваться и то и другое. За примером далеко ходить не надо. В argparse если передать некорректные аргументы из терминала, метод parse_args() вбрасывает SystemExit. В stderr пишется текст, код завершения 2. Казалось бы всё отлично, но нет. Если отловить исключение, в stderr всё равно будет тот же вывод. Чего по идее не должно быть, если исключение отловлено. Получается в модуле написано что-то вроде этого:

```
print(text, file=sys.stderr)
exit(2)
```

Как по мне выглядит коряво.
Отсюда вопрос: можно ли задать и код завершения, и текст вывода в stderr в исключении python?

Comment: Такое [предложение](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/80872) есть, но на данный момент не реализовано

Comment: 19 год, ужас. Не дождусь боюсь реализации-то(

Comment: @MyName возможно что-то можно придумать, но для начала хотелось бы чуть лучше понять какую именно задачу Вы этим пытаетесь решить, Ваша программа использует `argparse` и Вы не хотите видеть ошибку в консоли или что-то другое? Просто когда лучше понятна цель быстрее найти решение или убедится что его нет, ну собственно и комментарий Андрея и Ваш вопрос включает тезис что решения нет, как и документация функции и даже в исходниках [так](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2b94a05a0e45e4aae030a28b716a038ef529f8ef/Python/sysmodule.c#L849C39-L849C43) написано. Надеюсь вопрос не риторический)

Comment: @MyName кстати, в [argparse.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2b94a05a0e45e4aae030a28b716a038ef529f8ef/Lib/argparse.py#L2639) видно что если `message` будет пуст то он и не выведется, как минимум можно почистить в обработчике.

Comment: @DaniilLoban я скорее из академического интереса спрашиваю

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с наследованием ошибки, мне кажется вполне нормальным. В качестве альтернативы с наследованием возможно подойдет следующий вариант, не требующий создания дополнительных сущностей, основанный на tuple в сообщении об ошибке:

```
import sys

def test():
  sys.exit((2,'Ошибка'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  exit_code, exit_message = 0, None
  try:
    test()  
  except SystemExit as e:
    exit_code, exit_message = e.args
    sys.exit(exit_code) # инициализируем ошибку только с кодом
  finally:
    if (exit_message):
      sys.stderr.write(f'ERROR: {exit_message}\n')
```

Проверка:

```
$ gdb --args python3 test.py 
(gdb) r 
...
ERROR: Ошибка
[Inferior 1 (process 9645) exited with code 02]
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно имитировать нужное поведение:

```
import sys


class SystemQuit(SystemExit):
    def __init__(self, message, exit_code):
        super().__init__()
        self.__message = message
        self.__exit_code = exit_code

    def process(self):
        if self.__message is not None:
            print(self.__message, file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(self.__exit_code)


def quit(message, exit_code):
    raise SystemQuit(message, exit_code)


def main():
    try:
        print('before')
        quit('something went wrong', 2)
        print('after')
    except SystemQuit as e:
        e.process()


main()
```

> ```
> $ python quit.py
> before
> something went wrong
>
> $ echo $?
> 2
> ```